# Minimal example of Python interpreter embedding segfaults

Tags: python, c, build

The example I copied from here: https://docs.python.org/3.5/extending/embedding.html

```
#include <Python.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    wchar_t *program = Py_DecodeLocale(argv[0], NULL);
    if (program == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: cannot decode argv[0]\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    Py_SetProgramName(program);  /* optional but recommended */
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("from time import time,ctime\n"
                       "print('Today is', ctime(time()))\n");
    Py_Finalize();
    PyMem_RawFree(program);
    return 0;
}
```

If compiled and linked like this:

```
gcc -fno-diagnostics-color -Wall -Wno-unused-function -fPIC -ggdb \
    -I. -I/usr/include/python3.5m -c test_embed.c -o test_embed.o
gcc -fno-diagnostics-color -Wall -Wno-unused-function -fPIC -ggdb \
    -I. -I/usr/include/python3.5m -shared -lpython3.5m ./test_embed.o \
    -o test_embed
```

segfaults when run and destroys the stack to the point it's impossible to figure out what happened.  Do I need any specific settings to compile this?

---

When I use compiler options as given by `/usr/bin/python3.5-config --cflags` and `/usr/bin/python3.5-config --ldconfig`, the example won't build because it cannot find the symbols in shared object.

---

Per requested, here's the compile and link commands and the error output:

```
$ gcc $(python3.5-config --cflags) -c test_embed.c -o test_embed.o
$ gcc $(python3.5-config --ldflags) ./test_embed.o -o test_embed
./test_embed.o: In function `main':
redacted/test_embed.c:6: undefined reference to `Py_DecodeLocale'
redacted/test_embed.c:11: undefined reference to `Py_SetProgramName'
redacted/test_embed.c:12: undefined reference to `Py_Initialize'
redacted/test_embed.c:13: undefined reference to `PyRun_SimpleStringFlags'
redacted/test_embed.c:15: undefined reference to `Py_Finalize'
redacted/test_embed.c:16: undefined reference to `PyMem_RawFree'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
$ python3.5-config --ldflags
-L/usr/lib/python3.5/config-3.5m-x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib -lpython3.5m -lpthread -ldl  -lutil -lm  -Xlinker -export-dynamic -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions
```

Comment: Is this python3.5m something that came from a package (like apt or rpm), or did you configure and compile it from source?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Sorry, it was installed from Ubuntu PPA. I also have Python 3.6 compiled from source, but this one isn't mine.

Answer (score 1):

Your `test_embed` binary segfaults because a binary built with `--shared` (a shared library) is not intended to be run.

Diagnosing the build problem which led you to erroneously use `--shared` in the linker command line might require additional detail, such as the specific `gcc` commands you used and the error messages from running them, or the output of `python3.5-config` on your system, perhaps both. If I compile your test program with the following commands it does not segfault (it prints the expected output).

```
gcc $(python3.5-config --cflags) -c test_embed.c -o test_embed.o
gcc $(python3.5-config --ldflags) ./test_embed.o -o test_embed
```

On my system the output of `python3.5-config --ldflags` does not include `--shared`.

The documentation for building [Building C and C++ Extensions](https://docs.python.org/3.5/extending/building.html) includes sample compilation commands in its [distutils](https://docs.python.org/3.5/extending/building.html#building-c-and-c-extensions-with-distutils) section. The sample link command there includes `--shared` for the `.so` file it generates, but that `.so` file is intended to be imported into a python interpreter, not invoked as a command.

Comment: I think I added `--shared` by copy-pasting the command line `setuptools` generates when it compiles C modules. However, I also remember `gcc` complaining about `-fPIC` (it wanted it to be there), while it wasn't in the flags. Does Python really not use this option? (I know some other interpreters don't because of how they manage their own runtime, but if Python does that too, then it will also mean that the embedding program should do the same...

Comment: It makes sense to use `--shared` when compiling C code for a python module. The binaries generated that way conventionally have `.so` as their suffix, and are not intended to be invoked as executables. The complaint which recommends `-fPIC` occurs if you try to link object modules into a shared object, i.e. only if you specify `--shared` in the link command.

Comment: So, Python must be compiled without `-fPIC`? It's not a big concern for me, since this kind of embedding is only for testing the C modules in isolation. But isn't this really a concern for everyone who uses CPython?

Comment: Also, when I do it like this, the linking doesn't work: everything included from `<Python.h>` is undefined.

Comment: Perhaps you can edit the question to specify the link command which fails, and its error output.

Comment: I've appended this info to the question.

Comment: If you add `-Xlinker --verbose` to the linker command line the additional output (probably too voluminous to include here in its entirety) should tell you where the linker is finding `libpython3.5m.so`. On my system the linker finds `/usr/lib/python3.5/config-3.5m-x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.5m.so`, which has the required symbols (via a symlink). If your linker finds `libpython3.5m.so` in the same directory, perhaps there is a problem with your python installation.