# argc is always zero

Tags: python, c, build, gdb

This is a follow-up question to this one: [Minimal example of Python interpreter embedding segfaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49551375/minimal-example-of-python-interpreter-embedding-segfaults) .

When I compile the program like this:

```
gcc -fno-diagnostics-color -Wall -Wno-unused-function \
    -I. -fPIC -g3 -shared -I/usr/include/python3.5m \
    -I/usr/include/python3.5m -Wno-unused-result \
    -Wsign-compare -g \
    -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python3.5-nLrllb/python3.5-3.5.3=. \
    -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security \
    -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes \
    -L/usr/lib/python3.5/config-3.5m-x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib \
    -lpython3.5m -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm -Xlinker -export-dynamic \
    -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions ./main.o ./binparser.o \
    -o protopy
```

The large number of options is due to running:

`/usr/bin/python3.5-config --cflags` and `/usr/bin/python3.5-config --ldconfig` and trying to incorporate them into the build ( `-fPIC` appears to be mandatory, and without `-shared` it won't link, since, I think, this is the only way you can link with Python library.

When I then run the compiled program in GDB, `main()` always gets no arguments.  No matter if I do `r foo bar` or `set args foo bar`.

Any ideas?  I don't know what all of the gcc options here do, so, maybe it's some of those?

Comment: @wvxvm out of interest - how is your main function prototyped?

Comment: @Neil `int main(int argc, char** argv);`

Comment: You explicitely mention running in GDB. Do you get parameters when you run your program from command line?

Comment: @Gerhardh what do you mean? I wrote above how I supply arguments to the program using `gdb` commands. When I run the program outside debugger, it segfaults before any user code can run, so I cannot tell you if it ever sees the arguments, guess not, but I cannot tell for sure, the program must be too butchered to actually say something with certainly about it.

Comment: You can easliy tell if your program gets parameters by printing `argc` and `argv`. I want to figure out if you have a problem in your program or in usage of GDB

Comment: @Gerhardh I just wrote that the program crashes before it gets into `main`... so, no, I cannot print those arguments.

Comment: This is probably caused by the python-config options. Try to compile and link only with `-I/usr/include/python3.5m -lpython3.5m -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm`.

Comment: What is gcc and gdb version? Looks like gdb can't load symbols by some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unreasonable to expect `gdb` to set a meaningful breakpoint in a shared object which is being invoked as though it is an executable. If you use `strace` on a binary built as described in [the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49551375/minimal-example-of-python-interpreter-embedding-segfaults), you'll see an immediate segfault, before any of the system calls you'd ordinarily see from the dynamic linker when using `strace` on a genuine executable.

Comment: Thank you. That would make sense. I doubted about what `-shared` actually does, but thought that in this context it means that other code linked against program code will not be linked in. Apparently, I was wrong, thanks for clarifying this.